# Did the House of Lords hear appeal cases in the main Lords’ chamber of Parliament?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-history, appeal, uk-supreme-court, house-of-lords

I suppose that the appeal cases were only ever heard by the law lords, in actuality a subsection rather than any plenary session of the house, so was it just a smaller session in the main canonically iconic chamber, or was it held in some smaller and more law court-like room similar to that in which the UKSC/SCOTUK now sits?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://www.supremecourt.uk/about/appellate-committee.html

> Before the second world war, the Law Lords used to hear appeals each day in the chamber of the House of Lords.
>
> After the House of Commons was bombed, the Law Lords moved their hearings to a nearby committee room to escape the noise of the building repairs, constituting themselves as an Appellate Committee for the purpose. In fact, this temporary arrangement proved so successful that it became permanent, and continued for the remainder of the Appellate Committee’s life.

Comment: Might be worth adding that even after this move, the verdicts in cases were still read out in the Lords Chamber, and had to be approved there - though in practice that was a formality. This all ended with the creation of the Supreme Court.

Comment: They did use the chamber occasionally for hearings - clustered together at the north end, by the bar of the house. The crossbenches had to be removed to make room for rather awkward little desks, with counsel and visitors crammed in behind the bar, so this wasn't a favoured option. Earlier still, the Lord Chancellor had to open the proceedings from the woolsack, then hastily meander down the length of the chamber to sit with the other judges. They used the chamber like this as late as summer 2009, during the Parliamentary recess before the Supreme Court first sat in October.

Comment: https://parliamentlive.tv/event/index/ba970e07-8497-4623-a4d9-3b9215ba449f?in=13:00:00 has an example (morning of 28 July 2009 related to planning law).  The most interesting part is the lunch adjournment after 13:00, moving from one end of the chamber to the other so as to consider a parliamentary motion. The barristers' wigs and gowns are good too when compared to the Law Lords wearing normal clothes.

Comment: For a fictional example, in the classic Ealing comedy [Kind Hearts And Coronets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_Hearts_and_Coronets), the main character (a duke) exercises his right to be tried before the House Of Lords, and the trial scene is set in the main chamber.

Comment: "Law Lord" is such a quintessentially British title.

Comment: @A.R. - just a couple of 19th century compromises: the Supreme Court of Judicature Act 1873 passed by the Liberals set up a Supreme Court of England (on two levels: the High Court and Court of Appeal) with plans to abolish the judicial role of the House of Lords.  They then lost the 1874 general election to the Conservatives who had campaigned to retained the House of Lords for final appeals, but realised there were not enough good judges already there and they did not want to create new hereditary peers who were not rich landowners.  So they invented Law Lords as life peers.